# How to get around UDF restriction on side-effecting operators?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions

Microsoft Books Online (BOL) on [Using Change Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645858.aspx) explains a misleading error messages for `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_*` & `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_*` when an invalid, out-of-range LSN (Log Sequence Number) has been passed to them.

---

```
Msg 313, Level 16, State 3, Line 1

An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_` ...

Msg 313, Level 16, State 3, Line 1

An insufficient number of arguments were supplied for the procedure or function `cdc.fn_cdc_get_net_changes_` ...
```

---

Their explanation on this misleading error message is as following

> Note:
>   It is recognized that the
>   message for Msg 313 is misleading and
>   does not convey the actual cause of
>   the failure. This awkward usage stems
>   from the inability to raise an
>   explicit error from within a TVF.
>   Nevertheless, the value of returning a
>   recognizable, if inaccurate, error was
>   deemed preferable to simply returning
>   an empty result. An empty result set
>   would not be distinguishable from a
>   valid query returning no changes.

Here is a demonstration of what the note meant [`RAISERROR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx)
[image]

There are times when I'd like to throw an error and you cannot use [`TRY..CATCH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) within UDF since it also has a side-effect like `RAISERROR`.
 
 
Now the **question** is, how do *you* get around this problem? 
I am sure that you have faced with this restriction before. 
What alternative would you suggest?

---

**[UPDATE]** Let's suppose that you are forced to use `UDF`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case of your function which returns BIT, I'll return NULL back to the calling code, and at some point after using the function check for NULL, and throw an error then.